What does ～を得て mean here?
From Kokoro's chapter 9 footnote on 日光:

東照宮や温泉で名高い栃木県の観光地。江戸以来多くの参詣客、観光客を集めていたが、明治に入って東北本線の開通に続き宇都宮―日光間の鉄道開通や、洋式ホテルの開業などによって人気はさらに高まり、西洋人たちも多く訪れるようになっていった。前注の箱根も含めて、「先生」たちが訪れているのは、迅速な交通機関と快適な滞在施設を得て、魅力を増した伝統的な観光地である。東京からこれらへの旅行が「一週間以内」の旅程で無理なく楽しめるようになったのは鉄道の威力である。

What's the purpose of ～を得て in the bold sentence? I think it has a similar function as ～を経て.

「迅速な交通機関と快適な滞在施設を得て、魅力を増した」 is a relative clause modifying 伝統的な観光地. Within this clause, (1) 迅速な交通機関と快適な滞在施設を得て is subordinate to (2) 魅力を増した. You could say that (1) expresses the "means" or "manner" by which (2) happened ("...tourism location that increased its appeal by obtaining rapid transit infrastructure and comfortable lodging"). Alternatively, you could simply see (1) and (2) as sequential actions ("...increased its appeal after obtaining rapid transit...").
I've translated 得る as "obtain", and hopefully you can see why it makes sense to use a word that means "obtain" in this sentence. As for 経る, this has a few meanings: to pass (mainly of time), to pass through, to experience -  these don't work too well with our object, 迅速な交通機関と快適な滞在施設. The tourism location isn't "passing through" or "experiencing" transit and lodging.

Thanks, I can't believe that I overlooked this obvious meaning.
